# ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy while using saveToCassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, cassandra, rdd

I am reading data from cassandra using cassandraTable() function of sqlContext. It will create a DataFrame. 
I am converting this Df to Rdd and mapping it to a case class object.
dataClass is a dataframe.
I have checked similar questions posted but none helped.

```
val dataClass = cartData.rdd.map({case Row(session_id : String, time_stamp : Date, data : String) => cartDataClass(session_id, time_stamp, data)})
```

Above anonymous function inside map function is creating problem. is it correct ? Looks like it is not able to serialize the function.

dataClass is an RDD[cartDataClass]
Now i am trying to save this RDD to cassandra.

```
dataClass.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")
```

But it is throwing this Exception :

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 26, 192.168.1.104): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2024)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This looks like some problem with Serialization of RDD.
RDDs are serializable so what can be the problem here ?
I am writing my script in an scala object main function, is it due to spark not being able to serialize scala object ?
Please help, i am new to both scala and spark.

Comment: I don't think this is a serialization problem. But it's hard to figure out your problem without seeing a definition of `cartDataClass`.

Comment: its a case class.

    case class cartDataClass(session_id : String, time_stamp : Date, data : String){
def modifyData() : cartDataClass {
// some code to change data field and return cartDataClass object
}

Answer (score 1):

If i might suggest. Just save the DataFrame itself to C*. The dataframe "write" method can be used with C* see

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#persisting-a-dataset-to-cassandra-using-the-save-command

Without knowing how `cartDataClass` is defined it's hard to know what could be going wrong in your dependency tree. My guess would be that the dependency tree for the RDD being serialized is having trouble with that type.

Answer (score -1):

```
new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
```

`local[2]` and its working

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).